# Check and count values of a table column and show them in a pie chart using SQLite database in C#.NET

Tags: c#, sqlite, pie-chart

I am trying to draw a simple pie chart where data will come from a SQLite database. I need to check a column of a table whether it has value 2 or 1 or 0. I have written 3 functions to check and count them. Table name is banana and column name is status. The table is like following

```
Id  B   M   status
1   10  101 2
2   11  102 2
3   11  103 0
4   12  104 1
5   13  105 1
6   13  105 0
7   14  106 1
8   14  106 2
```

The functions are

```
 public double countA()
        {
            return GetDoubleEntity("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banana WHERE banana.status = '2';");
        }        
 public double countB()
        {
            return GetDoubleEntity("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banana WHERE banana.status = '1';");
        }        
 public double countC()
        {
            return GetDoubleEntity("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banana WHERE banana.status = '0';");
        }
```

Then I have written following codes to draw the pie chart

```
    double Total, APercentage, BPercentage, CPercentage;                        

    Total= countA() + countB() + countC();          

    APercentage= (countA() * 100) / Total;
    BPercentage= (countB() * 100) / Total;
    CPercentage= (countC() * 100) / Total;

    //Take legend
    string[] xAxis = { "A", "B", "C" };

    //Take Percentage Values 
    double[] PiePercentage = { APercentage, BPercentage, CPercentage};

    Chart.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT";
    Chart.Series[0].LegendText = "#AXISLABEL";
    Chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis, PiePercentage);

    Chart.Series[0].Points[0].Color = Color.Green;
    Chart.Series[0].Points[1].Color = Color.Red;
    Chart.Series[0].Points[2].Color = Color.Yellow;
```

But, it is not showing results. Could anyone give me any hints what is wrong with it ? Is it problem with SQL queries or chart functions which are creating the problems ?

Comment: You need to tell us whether the problem is in the SQL Queries or the chart functions. What are the values of APercentage, BPercentage, and CPercentage when the code runs?

Comment: APercentage is the percentage of countA. its calculation is shown in the codes. same to BPercentage and CPercentage.

Comment: it is showing values of Total 0.

Comment: what is the type of status field in your SQL table?

Comment: are sql queries correct ?